# pickle не видит класс

Tags: python, python-2.x, pickle

У меня есть классы, находящиеся в одном файле, вместе с исполняемым кодом. После чего я создаю объект одного из классов, а затем его сохраняю с помощью pickle. В итоге, при загрузке из pickle я не могу загрузиться из-за ошибки:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Item1'

В одном файле объявлю 2 класса (в классах нужно дописать конструкторы). Сохраню один из объектов в pickle и загружу его (для проверки):

file1.py:

```
class Item0:
    pass

class Item1(Item0)
    pass

t = Item1()

with open('1.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pkl.dump(t, f)
with open('1.pkl', 'rb') as fid:
    print pkl.load(fid)
```

В таком случае всё сохраняется и загружается. Создадим другой файл. И попробуем загрузить сохранённый объект оттуда:

file2.py:

```
with open('1.pkl', 'rb') as fid:
    print pkl.load(fid)
```

В таком случае, будет получена вышеуказанная ошибка. Импорт соответствующих классов из file1.py не помогает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда вы модуль напрямую выполняете как Питон-скрипт, то его имя `__main__`, в каком бы файле он не лежал.  Когда вы импортирует модуль, то ему уже подходящее имя даётся: file0 для `file0.py` в [вашем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/716076/23044).

pickle сохраняет имена модулей, где классы определены: в коде в вопросе это `__main__`  (file1.py). Когда вы file2.py как скрипт выполняете, то он становится `__main__`, но в нём соответствующие классы не определены, поэтому вы получаете AttributeError.

Когда вы импортирует классы из другого модуля, то его имя и сохраняется в pickle (file0 вместо `__main__`), поэтому загрузка начинает работать когда уже другой модуль является `__main__`.

Выносить определения в другой модуль не обязательно, достаточно поменять file1.py:

```
class Item1:
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pickle
    from file1 import Item1

    t = Item1()
    with open('1.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(t, f)
```

Тогда file2.py без ошибки заработает.

Answer (score 0):

Решение очень простое. Необходимо вынести оба класса в отдельный файл и импортировать их оттуда:

file0.py:

```
class Item0:
    pass

class Item1(Item0)
    pass
```

file1.py:

```
from file0 import Item1, Item2

t = Item1()

with open('1.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pkl.dump(t, f)
with open('1.pkl', 'rb') as fid:
    print pkl.load(fid)
```

file2.py:

```
with open('1.pkl', 'rb') as fid:
    print pkl.load(fid)
```